# How to check a range of candles on chart?

Tags: pine-script

I want to check `close` parameter of previous 50 candles.

I should find the minimum/maximum of the range, and it must be lower/upper than current bar close.

How should I specify the range? I'm a newbie to Pine Script. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
highestClose = highest(close, 50)
lowestClose = lowest(close, 50)

closeRange = highestClose - lowestClose
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this in one statement by using the [range()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_range) built-in function.

```
closeRange = range(close, 50)
```